# How to use awk inside git --msg-filter

Tags: bash, awk, git-rewrite-history

i am trying to clean up some git history. For instance, trim all lines in my commits messages. I need to be able to do something like:

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat | awk '{$1=$1;print}'' HEAD
```

this, of course, will fail because of my bad usage of Apostrophes.

It does not work either if I try to escape then or use double apostrophes.

As an example of what I need to process take this:

```
    Add cool service to application

Related: ISSUE-3
```

This is the result of appending related issue identifier at end of commit and remove it from my summary line, note the space(s) at beggining of commit summary. It is mostly those commit summary what i want to trim with awk.

Can anybody help me with my limited bash skills?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us an input and tell us which lines you would like to avoid?

Comment: I have re-edited to show examples @Inian. Thanks!

Comment: Is it always same two lines after your message that needs to be removed?

Comment: The spaces before and after "Add cool service to application". Trim spaces in that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following command :

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat | awk '{$1=$1;print}'' HEAD
```

the expression between the innermost single quotes is not escaped and $1 is replaced by value

```
git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat | awk '\''{$1=$1;print}'\' HEAD
```

may be valid. Try also to add echo command at the beginning of the line

```
echo git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat | awk '{$1=$1;print}'' HEAD
echo git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat | awk '\''{$1=$1;print}'\' HEAD
```

or clearer adding `printf "'%s'\n"`

```
printf "'%s'\n" git filter-branch -f --msg-filter 'cat | awk '\''{$1=$1;print}'\' HEAD
```